# Como contar quantos caracteres há numa seleção?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, extensão

Existe alguma maneira, truque ou extensão para Visual Studio 2015 que me conte **quantos caracteres há na seleção que fiz**, incluindo espaços ou caracteres nulos?

**Observação:** eu quero contar a seleção do próprio Visual Studio, do seu próprio editor de texto, não estou fazendo um projeto que conte seleções.

Comment: A sua aplicação é **Web Form**, **Windows Forms** ou ...???

Comment: Isso não faz diferença, eu quero a seleção do próprio Visual Studio, no seu próprio editor de códigos.

Comment: Então, por favor, coloque essa informação, que o texto é o código da sua aplicação!

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que [uma resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3317013/221800) faz mais ou menos o que deseja. Seria algo assim:

```
using System;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80; //não sei se precisa de todos eles
using EnvDTE90;
using EnvDTE90a;
using EnvDTE100;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class CountNonWhiteSpaceCharacters {
    void Count() {
        //coloca onde quiser, pode ser no status, abrir outro tipo de controle, etc.
        MsgBox("Count " + DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection().Text.Length.ToString());
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WPF/VisualStudio.cs).

Precisa registrar a essa extensão. Há [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que pode ajudar se nunca criou uma extensão para o Visual Studio.

Comment: sério que vou ter que compilar uma extensão para só me mostrar quantas letrinhas tem numa seleção? ele não vem com isso "de fábrica"?

Comment: Não: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/7141458-show-count-of-selected-characters

Comment: O VS tem umas coisas meio bobas. Até pra por comentário em itálico precisa de extensão. É uma ferramenta poderosa, mas tem muita coisa do tipo "eu que sou desenvolvedor do VS não uso isso, então não precisa".

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância, @bigown, mas eu não achei nada sobre o link que tu me mandou: http://prntscr.com/cutdag

Comment: Ah, agora que vi que era um Feedback... "we are not including it in our plans at present".